# Separate them vertically with some white space

Tags: html, css, image

If this is the question:
Coding in the CSS panel on the right, style images so they center. Separate them vertically with some white space.
Would the following be OK?

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 2em auto;
}
```

Comment: it should have a 2em gap below each ....  if that is the answer ;)

Comment: Your css is basically ok. Add `border: 0;` to be sure that the image will not show unwanted borders. Maybe you want to give the image a `width` and `height: auto;` to set dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

To center images horizontally, while adding some vertical white space between them you can use the following CSS shorthand:

```
/* Margin of 2em along bottom, Margin of auto left/right */
margin: 0 auto 2em;
```

Here's a working example:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 2em;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x150" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x150" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30x150" />
```

For more information on the `margin` property, and examples of valid short-hand syntax, [see this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#More_examples)